# babelを利用した環境をrails4で構築することは可能ですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

検索して、参考サイトを探しているのですが
babelを利用してes6でプログラミングができる環境をrailsで構築する具体的な方法がわかりません。

es6についてまったく経験が無いのですが
そもそもそのような環境をrails上で構築することができるのでしょうか？

参考サイトや導入方法など、簡単なものでもよいので意見がほしいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Gemfile
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'sprockets-es6'
```

Gemfileに上記を追加し、`javascripts`ディレクトリに`hoge.es6`ファイルを作成したら
うまく出来ました。

なぜsprocketsという名前のgemを追加するとbabelを利用できるのかはよくわかりません。